# Visual Basic Input Validation

Tags: vb.net

I am new to Visual Basic programming. I'm using a multi-line textbox to accept only numerical inputs from the users.

I need to remove any white space before adding it to my listbox. For example like (               8) becomes 8 when added into the listbox and I shouldn't let the user proceed if there is no input or only whitespace as an input. Thank you in advance :)

```
For i As Integer = 0 To Val(TxtInput.Lines.Count) - 1
    If TxtInput.Lines(i) = "" Then 'Ignores newline inputs
        'Placeholder Comment 
    ElseIf IsNumeric(TxtInput.Lines(i)) Then 'Tests for Numbers
        Temp.LbInput.Items.Add(TxtInput.Lines(i))
        Temp.Show()
    Else
        MsgBox("Your input must only be in numbers, check for invalid inputs!", 1, "Error")
        Temp.LbInput.Items.Clear()
        Return
    End If
Next
```

Comment: [Trimming and Removing Characters from Strings in .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/trimming)

Comment: Tried but doesn't works. Thanks :)

Comment: It's Visual Basic programming not Visual Basics programming. I have questions... Why are you using a 'multi-line' textbox to accept numeric values? You tagged your code as VB.NET but it has VB6 syntax.. (Val) (IsNumeric). So let me get this clear, you just want to check the text in a textbox is a number? Is that correct?

Comment: @Blacky_99 If you change all occurrences of `TxtInput.Lines(i)` in the code you showed to `TxtInput.Lines(i).Trim()` it will work.

Comment: @video.baba Val and IsNumeric are still in VB.NET, although their use for new code is perhaps not advisable.

Comment: @Andrew Morton I know.  You shouldn't be using them in .NET.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Thank you very much it works

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just store the trimmed line into a variable

```
For i As Integer = 0 To TxtInput.Lines.Count - 1
    Dim line As String = TxtInput.Lines(i).Trim() '<======================

    If line = "" Then 'Ignores newline inputs
        'Placeholder Comment 
    ElseIf IsNumeric(line) Then 'Tests for Numbers
        Temp.LbInput.Items.Add(line)
        Temp.Show()
    Else
        MsgBox("Your input must only be in numbers, check for invalid inputs!", 1, "Error")
        Temp.LbInput.Items.Clear()
        Return
    End If
Next
```

Also, `TxtInput.Lines.Count` is an `Integer` already. No need to convert with `Val`, which, by the way, converts it into a `Double`.

Note that you can add items of any type to the `ListBox`, so you could as well convert the line into the desired type. I don't know if you need `Integer` or `Double`. Let's assume that you only want integer numbers. then you can change the code to

```
If TxtInput.Lines.Count = 0 Then
    MsgBox("You have not entered anything. Please enter a number!", 1, "Error")
Else
    For i As Integer = 0 To TxtInput.Lines.Count - 1
        Dim line As String = TxtInput.Lines(i).Trim()
        Dim number As Integer

        If line = "" Then
            MsgBox("Your input is empty. Please enter some numbers!", 1, "Error")
        ElseIf Integer.TryParse(line, number) Then 'Tests for Numbers
            Temp.LbInput.Items.Add(number)
            Temp.Show()
        Else
            MsgBox("Please enter only valid numbers!", 1, "Error")
            Temp.LbInput.Items.Clear()
            Return
        End If
    Next
End If
```

(Code changed according to your comments.)

If you want doubles, just declare `number` as `Double` and convert with `Double.TryParse(line, number)`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your clarification

Comment: btw how do i give them an error message for inputting ONLY white space as an input ?

Comment: Just replace your Placeholder Comment with MsgBox.

Comment: The MsgBox only works if i press space once or enter once. It doesn't works if I just leave the cursor blinking in the textbox

Comment: Because there are no lines, check the line count first... `If TxtInput.Lines.Count = 0 Then MessageBox`... Also IMHO use `MessageBox`, the other (MsgBox) is vb6 leftovers.

Comment: Thank you for your humble opinion and aid

Answer (score 0):

This is the kind of thing linq-to-objects was made for:

```
Dim result = TxtInput.Lines.
        Select(Function(line) line.Trim).
        Where(Function(line) Not String.IsNullOrWhitespace(line) AndAlso IsNumeric(line)).
        Select(Function(line) Val(line))
```

You can also do this:

```
Dim lines = TxtInput.Lines.Select(Function(line) line.Trim)
If lines.Any(Function(line) Not IsNumeric(line)) Then
    MsgBox("Your input must only be in numbers, check for invalid inputs!", 1, "Error")
    Exit Sub
Else
    Dim result = lines.Where(Function(line) Not String.IsNullOrWhitespace(line)).
                       Select(Function(line) Val(line))

    'Do more with "result" here

End If
```